# How to create a module in angular inside a component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to create a component dynamically inside another component. So that i can pass my dynamic html template directly to the decorater like this  @Component({
template: template
});

//code

```
 /**
 * @param template is html template
 * @param container is  @ViewChild('dynamicFront', { read: ViewContainerRef }) _containerFront: ViewContainerRef;
 */
private addComponent(template, container) {
    @Component({
      template: template
    })
    class DynamicComponent {
    constructor(public _parent: TemplateEditorComponent) {
      this._parent.templateForm.controls['field_heading'].valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
        console.log(value);
      })
    }

    }
    @NgModule({
        imports: [
            ReactiveFormsModule,
            BrowserModule,
            EditorModule
        ],
        declarations: [DynamicComponent, EditableDivDirective, InlineEditorDirective]
    })
    class DynamicComponentModule { }

    const mod = this.compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync(DynamicComponentModule);
    const factory = mod.componentFactories.find((comp) =>
      comp.componentType === DynamicComponent
    );
    const component = container.createComponent(factory);
}
```

and in html component iam showing the template like this

```
<ng-template #dynamicFront></ng-template>
```

iam getting some build errors like `template` is not string and all. The objective is to show my raw html which coming from the db and i need to edit text inside this raw html template and iam using tinymce for editing purpose inside this raw html.

Comment: Use `<ng-template>` instead dynamic component.

Comment: @anlijudavid i just updated my post

Answer (score 0):

If your component's template is required to be dynamic, you should aim to use `<ng-template>` or embedded components with inputs and outputs.

In case you're unclear on the ng-template directive, [here's a tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/).

---

Edit:

Your code is quite complicated for a simple use case. If all you're attempting to do is render different templates based on data in your controller, then you should focus on building out your existing template to be more dynamic.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="template == 1" 
              [ngTemplateOutlet]="template1" 
              [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{value: value}">
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="template == 2" 
              [ngTemplateOutlet]="template2" 
              [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{value: value}">
</ng-container>

...

<ng-template #template1 let-value="value">
    <div class="template-1-container">
        {{value}}
    </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #template2 let-value="value">
    <div class="template-2-container">
        {{value}}
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

And you could easily replace the templates with components if you needed the templates to perform some logic:

```html
<app-template-one *ngIf="template == 1"
                  [value]="value">
</app-template-one>

<app-template-two *ngIf="template == 1"
                  [value]="value">
</app-template-two>
```

Comment: hey i just updated my post,, please share if you got any solution

Comment: I've updated and added some code, but still unclear on what you're attempting to achieve.